# getElementsByTagName not a function?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I actually found this code on a previous post in relation to a question I asked, however, despite it seeming easy enough I can't get past doc.getElementsByTagName is not a function error.  Here is the sample code:

```
var addCssRule = (function() {
        var addRule;

        if (typeof document.styleSheets != "undefined" && document.styleSheets) {
            addRule = function(selector, rule, doc, el) {
                var sheets = doc.styleSheets, sheet;
                if (sheets && sheets.length) {
                    sheet = sheets[sheets.length - 1];
                    if (sheet.addRule) {
                        sheet.addRule(selector, rule)
                    } else if (typeof sheet.cssText == "string") {
                        sheet.cssText = selector + " {" + rule + "}";
                    } else if (sheet.insertRule && sheet.cssRules) {
                        sheet.insertRule(selector + " {" + rule + "}", sheet.cssRules.length);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            addRule = function(selector, rule, doc, el) {
                el.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(selector + " {" + rule + "}"));
            };
        }

        return function(selector, rule, doc) {
            doc = doc || document;

            var head = doc.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
            if (head && addRule) {
                var styleEl = doc.createElement("style");
                styleEl.type = "text/css";
                styleEl.media = "screen";
                head.appendChild(styleEl);
                addRule(selector, rule, doc, styleEl);
                styleEl = null;
            }
        };
    })();

    addCssRule("ol", "color:red", tinyMCE.Editor[0]);
```

I'm quite certain that the code is correct.  I'm thinking I misunderstand how the tinymce variable is being passed.  What do you think?

Comment: What browsers give the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problems here are**

**1. You do not call your function using a document as 3rd parameter - it is an editor instance.**
To fix this you should use `addCssRule("ol", "color:red", tinyMCE.Editor[0].getDoc());` or `addCssRule("ol", "color:red", tinyMCE.get(editor_id).getDoc());`

**2. You are reffering to the wrong document inside your function.** What you do is reffering to the main windows document and not the document of the editor instances iframe (that is the one you want the css rule apply to)! You need to reffer to `tinyMCE.Editor[0].getDoc()` here too.

Comment: I had to do a little bit of editing but this worked quite well.  Thank you!!!  I've been pounding my head on this for several days.  Thanks a billion.

Comment: glad to have been able to help

Answer (score 5):

The third parameter you're passing into your function is `tinyMCE.Editor[0]`.  Does *that* have the `getElementsByTagName` function?

Comment: The band of Jacobs strike again! :)

Comment: You know... I guess I don't know enough about the tinymce api to tell you that.  I have been trying to avoid passing the name in manually because I want the function to be as oop as possible.  I guess I need to do more research on how tinymce actually stores the object.  Thanks for the quick reply though.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks fine to me, although I do think that in your case, the last argument to `addCssRule` is not a DOM element. At least that's what would be causing such an error to be raised.